# Share screen and send audio with two publishers

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I am trying to share screen and send audio at the same time, I have managed to follow the instructions of Adam Ullman from this link [Opentok Screen Sharing with Audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300418/opentok-screen-sharing-with-audio) but the sound is quite bad , it is heard doubled and with very poor quality.

I have asked the technical support of tokbox and they tell me that another option is to use the same person with two publishers (one for screen and another to share audio). The problem is that when I do this or share a screen or share the camera + microphone, how can I make the other person see the shared screen and listen to me?

Another option I have is: is there any way to improve the sound of setusermedia? or avoid duplicating sound?

I have the following code:

```
screenSharingPublisher = Promise.all ([
                        OT.getUserMedia ({
                            videoSource: 'screen'
                        }),
                        OT.getUserMedia ({
                            videoSource: null
                        })
                    ])
                        .then (([screenStream, micStream]) => {
                        return OT.initPublisher (null, {
                            videoSource: screenStream.getVideoTracks () [0],
                            audioSource: micStream.getAudioTracks () [0]
                        });
                });

                    screenSharingPublisher.then (publisher => {
                        l.publish (publisher, handleErrorScreen);
                }). catch (handleErrorScreen);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Tokbox QA staff here,

I think what you need is to create two publishers, one with just video (screensharing) and another one with audio and video (camera + microphone), against the same session. With that, other users subscribing to that sessionId would see your screen, and hear your voice.
If your sound is heard doubled, maybe you're publishing your microphone twice.

I hope this helps.